# AppDynamics to group REST endpoints containing UUIDs as a single business transaction

Tags: java, rest, jboss, resteasy, appdynamics

I have a web application running on JBoss/Wildfly and using RESTEasy. I'm monitoring it with AppDynamics. I've configured my business transaction detection to use a Java Servlet.
This just about works, but some of my REST paths contain UUIDs, for example:

```
/data/scenario/d345d238-e0d2-4e01-a96e-4bf11290ce1d/job
```

Each time this end-point is invoked with a different UUID, AppD treats it as a different business transaction. Is there a way to make AppD recognise UUIDs within a path, and group these into a single business transaction? Something like:

```
/data/scenario/{id}/job
```

I should be able to do it by applying a regex to the request's path info:

```
request.getPathInfo().replaceAll(
    "[0-9a-f]{8}\\-[0-9a-f]{4}\\-[0-9a-f]{4}\\-[0-9a-f]{4}\\-[0-9a-f]{12}", 
    "{id}")
```

or even just

```
request.getPathInfo().replaceAll("[0-9a-f\\-]{36}", "{id}")
```

but I can't figure out how to escape it properly.

```
${getPathInfo().replaceAll([0-9a-f\\-]{36}, id)}
```

doesn't work, and neither does

```
${getPathInfo().replaceAll(\[0\-9a\-f\\\\-\]\{36\}, id)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuration->Instrumentation->Transaction Detection->Add

On the "Split Transactions Using Request Data" section you must choose "*Specific URI Segments*"
Segment Numbers: 1,2,4

In your case transaction name will be "/data/scenario/job"

Sample Configuration:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works in the example URI I gave, but we have lots of endpoint URIs that contain UUIDs is different positions. I need something more general.

Comment: If you don't have a standard on your URL naming, I have suggested to use Header, Cookie, HTTP Parameter or Method parameter instead of regex.
I believe that you can find a unique value which you can split your transactions.